# Sending/recieving data via HTTP to a php file ( as a server)

Tags: php, http

so im trying to send gps data from an arduino to my php file that stores the data in a database.
the command that sends the data is the following `AT+CIPSTART="TCP","my_hostname","80"
AT+CIPSEND > POST /callback HTTP/1.1`
The probleme is that i dont knwo how to set up the url that contain my php file, for example `AT+CIPSTART="TCP","my_hostname/wamp/pr/server.php"`
my php code is the following : `

```
if (!empty($_GET['ID']) && !empty($_GET['latitude']) &&
    !empty($_GET['longitude']) && !empty($_GET['date']) &&
    !empty($_GET['time']) && !empty($_GET['speed'])) {

    function getParameter($par, $default = null){
        if (isset($_GET[$par]) && strlen($_GET[$par])) return $_GET[$par];
        elseif (isset($_POST[$par]) && strlen($_POST[$par])) 
            return $_POST[$par];
        else return $default;
    }

    $file = 'gps.txt';
    $ID = getParameter("ID");
    $lat = getParameter("latitude");
    $lon = getParameter("longitude");
    $time = getParameter("time");
    $date = getParameter("date");
    $speed = getParameter("speed");
    $person = $ID.";".$lat.";".$lon.";".$time.";".$date.";".$speed."\n";
    echo "
        DATA:\n
         ID: ".$ID."\n
        Latitude: ".$lat."\n
        Longitude: ".$lon."\n
        Time: ".$time."\n
        date: ".$date."\n
        Speed: ".$speed;


    if (!file_put_contents($file, $person, FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX))
        echo "\n\t Error saving Data\n";
    else echo "\n\t Data Save\n";
}
else {
    }
```

?>`

do i suppose to get the data like this, thanks for all answers

Comment: Point to a simple script that dumps the contents of `$_REQUEST`.  Note that your data might be in `$_POST` or it might just be raw input data, in which case you'll need to `$data=file_get_contents("php://input");`. But start with `<?php print_r($_REQUEST); ?>` and see what that gets you